# Open file with any application using xdg-open

Tags: command-line, xdg-open

How to open files without default application using xdg-open file_name? xdg-open file_name opens the file in default application. To play video files, it always opens with vlc which is set to default. If I want to open with media player, what will be the xdg-open code?

Comment: Just a side note, since it's already been answered that xdg-open will only open the default application for the file type. Check out http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/xdg-open.1.html especially the links to xdg-mime and xdg-settings for info on how to list the default types and change them from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open a file with a specific application, use that application's command directly instead of `xdg-open`. `xdg-open`'s purpose is to open the file with the associated application.

For example, with the default media player, Totem, the command is `totem`, so you'd do:

```
totem path/to/file.avi
```

If you want to use `mplayer`, do:

```
mplayer path/to/file.avi
```

and so on.